# Replacing existing video audio with a new one and loop the audio until video finish [FFMPEG]

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I would like to replace the existing audio from the video with a new one and  the updated audio will loop until the video finish [as audio duration can be lower than video duration]. I've tried with below command and looping is working but how to replace existing audio ?

`String[] command = new String[]{"-y", "-i", videoPath ,"-filter_complex", "amovie="+audioPath+":loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aud];[0:a][aud]amix[a]", "-map", "0:v" ,"-map", "[a]", "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac", "-shortest","-preset", "ultrafast", videoOutputDestination};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply omit the amix filter.

Replace:

```
amovie="+audioPath+":loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aud];[0:a][aud]amix[a]
```

With:

```
amovie="+audioPath+":loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[a]
```